# ubuntu server tar -xvf failed for solr.tar.gz

Tags: tar, ubuntu-18.04, solr

I am trying to extract solr server downloaded from https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/lucene/solr/7.7.2/solr-7.7.2.tgz

But am getting an error on ubuntu server. `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format`

I can confirm that I extracted this file with no trouble on windows 10 using winrar. What could be the problem

```
root@ubuntulondon:~# tar -xvf solr-7.7.2.tgz

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
root@ubuntulondon:~#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to verify the checksum of the downloaded file?
It is possible that it got corrupted during the download somehow, or that the download was aborted prematurely.

Try downloading the `.sha512` checksum file (store it in the same directory as the tgz with solr) and run:

```
$ sha512sum -c solr-7.7.2.tgz.sha512
```

If the checksum matches, it outputs

```
solr-7.7.2.tgz: OK
```

If it doesn't, it outputs

```
solr-7.7.2.tgz: FAILED
sha512sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
```

Maybe simply downloading it again will solve the problem for you. :)

Comment: wget is downloading an incomplete file (in Kilobytes) instead of the real file (in Megabytes). Dont know why. The server is on digitalocean

Comment: Are you wgetting the exact same URL you wrote in your question? If yes, then that is the problem. That URL (https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/lucene/solr/7.7.2/solr-7.7.2.tgz) leads only to a webpage where you are supposed to choose a mirror to download from.
If you wget one of the mirror URLs, then it works. Try wgetting from either the [US mirror](https://www-us.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/7.7.2/solr-7.7.2.tgz) or the [EU mirror](https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/7.7.2/solr-7.7.2.tgz)